# css tooltip position is not fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a tooltip using CSS. When I hover on the image gets displayed but the position is not fixed; it depends on the size of the image.

Here is the HTML:

```
   <section class="col col-2">
                  <input type="file" id="imgupload" accept="image/*" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this)" style="display:none"
                  />
                  <div class="pointer  imagewh">

                      <img type="image" data-ng-src="{{currIcon}}" ng-click="icon()" class="responsive" />

                    <span class="tooltiptext">Upload Icon</span>
                  </div>
                </section>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
 .pointer img {
        cursor: pointer;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-bottom: 7px;
    }

    .pointer .tooltiptext {
        visibility: hidden;
        width: 120px;
        background-color: black;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 6px;
        padding: 5px 0;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .pointer:hover .tooltiptext {
        visibility: visible;
    }

.responsive {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }    

.imagewh{
text-align:center;
width: 110px;
height: 110px;
}
.imagewh img{
position:relative;
top:50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

[image]
[image]

When I made the image responsive, the tooltip position keeps changing with each respective size of the images. How to make the position fixed? Please help me with this.

Comment: Can you please add your code into snippet?, So someone has quickly fixed your issue.

Comment: i dont have access to the page now. let me update the code

Comment: What element is the tooltips context e.g. what parent element has `position:relative`?

Comment: Fixed to what? Its original position within the page? If that's the case you'll have to move the element outside of its current position to reside alone in the DOM, outside of any parent, and from there give it a fixed position, then it will stick.

Comment: @girish, check my answer

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution, Its not perfect, but it will give you a good staring point.

Basically I made the `pointer` div `position:relative`, and the tooltip `position:absolute` and also changed `visibility:none` to `display:none`.

**Visiblilty** just hides the div, but the element still occupies space in the DOM.  `display:none` completely hides the div along with the space

And when you hover over the `pointer` div, I make the `tooltip` `display:block`

I removed the

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;}

body{padding:100px;}

.pointer{
position:relative;}

.pointer img {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
    width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.pointer .tooltiptext {
  display:none;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top:-30px;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}

.pointer:hover .tooltiptext {
  display:block;
}

.responsive {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.imagewh {
  text-align: center;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  border:1px solid black;/*for testing purpose*/
}
.bigimage{
 width: 210px;
 height: 210px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pointer  imagewh">
  <img type="image" data-ng-src="https://placehold.it/100x100" class="responsive" />
  <span class="tooltiptext">Upload Icon</span>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<div class="pointer  imagewh bigimage">
  <img type="image" data-ng-src="https://placehold.it/200x200" class="responsive" />
  <span class="tooltiptext">Upload Icon</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.pointer img {
     cursor: pointer;
     position: relative;
     display: inline-block;
     margin-bottom: 7px;
}
 .pointer .img-box {
     position:relative;
}
 .pointer .tooltiptext {
     visibility: hidden;
     width: 120px;
     background-color: black;
     color: #fff;
     text-align: center;
     border-radius: 6px;
     padding: 5px 0;
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 1;
}
 .img-box:hover .tooltiptext {
     visibility: visible;
     right: calc( 0% - 60px);
     top: -30px;
}
 .responsive {
     max-width: 100%;
     height: auto;
}
 .imagewh{
     text-align:center;
     width: 110px;
     height: 110px;
}
 .imagewh img{
     position:relative;
}
```

```html
<br>
<br>


<div class="pointer  imagewh">
  <div class="img-box">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSLsza5efhXDC69Ka0TuAMa1bfm2tbtUHXKVSKn3yzgVoiXbu6A" class="responsive" />
    <span class="tooltiptext">Upload Icon</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try this. It works fine.